# HTML banner vanishes when text too long

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I try to create a HTML banner with Javascript, where I map a standard accept and decline button from a websites cookie banner to a new one.

I stumbled over a strange behavior of HTML and I do not understand what happens here.
When the text in `textHeadline.innerHTML = "Cooki"` gets ?too long? the whole banner suddenly vanishes. So if I write `textHeadline.innerHTML = "Cookies are fun"` the banner is gone.
The same thing happens for `modalDialogText.innerHTML = "Click Decline"`.

Here is my complete code:

```js
globalThis.popupThePopupBanner = function(oldAccept, oldDecline) {

  parentDiv = document.createElement("div");
  parentDiv.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed !important; left: 16px !important; bottom: 16px !important;  width: 32rem; padding: 32px !important; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); z-index: 2001; overflow: auto; text-align: left;");


  siblingDiv = document.createElement("div");

  textDiv = document.createElement("div");
  textDiv.setAttribute("style", "text-align:left; color: rgb(255,255,255); background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0)");

  textHeadline = document.createElement("div");
  textHeadline.setAttribute("style", "text-align: center; color: rgb(255,255,255)");
  textHeadline.innerHTML = "Cook"
  modalDialogText = document.createElement("p");
  modalDialogText.innerHTML = "Click Decline";


  acceptButton = document.createElement("button");
  acceptButton.id = "acceptButton";
  acceptButton.textContent = "Accept";
  acceptButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    oldAccept.click();
    parentDiv.style.display = 'none';
  });

  declineButton = document.createElement("button");
  declineButton.id = "declineButton";
  declineButton.textContent = "Decline";
  declineButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    oldDecline.click();
    parentDiv.style.display = 'none';
  });

  textHeadline.appendChild(modalDialogText);

  textDiv.appendChild(textHeadline);
  textDiv.appendChild(acceptButton);
  textDiv.appendChild(declineButton);

  siblingDiv.appendChild(textDiv);

  parentDiv.appendChild(siblingDiv);

  document.body.appendChild(parentDiv);
}

globalThis.popupThePopupBanner();
```

This is how the banner looks like.[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce

Comment: As @Amith commented, this doesn't seem to be reproducible. Is there a reason that you're using `innerHTML` for `textHeadline` and `modalDialogText` but you're using `textContent` for others? Why not use `textContent` for those as well?

Comment: Ok. I now know what the problem is. It seems that you are not allowed to use the word "COOKIE" inside a new added HTML element.
Thank you all for your ideas. 
But now the next question: How can I use the word "Cookie"? And why is it not ?alllowed??

Comment: @Peter Do you really think the word cookie is the problem?

Comment: That sounds like a pretty odd issue. There are reserved words in JS but I don't believe cookie is one of them. But if that seems to be the issue, perhaps try specifying your character set in the meta tag?

Comment: @Juan Mendes it really is. I can write anything I want as long it does not contain the word cookie. 
@ Sensoray how can I set the meta tag? Maybe it is something that has to do with the Chrome Browser and some security feature concerning the misuse of Cookies?

Comment: @Peter I can guarantee you that is not the problem. You can search for a million websites that have the word cookie in them. You need to break down your problem to find where the bug is. It's **DEFINITELY NOT** because "you are not allowed to use the word "COOKIE" inside a new added HTML element". Your question has no  code, I'm not sure how you expect us to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Sensoray what are the meta tags?